# SQL - Possible to sum rows between particular values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

my apologies if this is a duplicate but I could not find an answer to my particular question. I have a table that lists products on a sales order, and their various quantities. Some products are components for other products and are denoted so with a flag. I would like to know if there is a way to have a running total for the parent/normal items that would reset on each parent/normal item.

Here is an example of the table data and my desired output:

`OrderNo    Item       Qty  Regular Line
 349443  AFU20451-KIT1  1   Y        1
 349443  AFU20451       0   N        2
 349443  HAWKE-14252    1   N        3
 349443  RGPM-25H4      1   N        4
 349443  AV-003-265     1   Y        5
 349443  AV-A00090-KIT  1   Y        6
 349443  AV-A00091      1   N        7
 349443  AV-A00090      1   N        8
 349443  AV-00043       1   N        9
 349443  AV457/310GR/FP 2   Y       10`

desired output:

`OrderNo Item          Qty
 349433  AFU20451-KIT1  3
 349433  AV-003-265     1
 349433  AV-A00090-KIT  4
 349433  AV457/310GR/FP 2`

As you can see, I would like to reset the sum every time it says Y, only include the parent item (I could get around this as I can keep the order of the items the same, could maybe use row number). I have been trying to use Over and Partition by in order to do this, but to no avail. Let me know if this is even possible or if you need any further information.

Comment: This is assuming some order to your records, but I can't discern how I would order them by looking at your data. How are you ordering this in your statement?

Comment: hint: partition by

Comment: The problem you are going to find here is a database has no inherent order.   Without an id column or some other method, you can't guarantee that the order of the records returned will be the same every time.  Do you have an ID field or something that maintains the order in your example?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didnt include it but theres a column that lists the items out in the exact order they should be in. The component products are always directly below the parent items.

Comment: Can you include that column as well that guarantees the order of the Item as shown above.. in your data screen above.

Comment: This would be a LOT easier if you have better normalization. We do kits and what we do is have an item number for the kit (which it looks like you do). Then we have a separate table that defines the components of that kit. Then it is pretty simple. You figure out how many items are in the kit and multiple that by the number of kits being purchased.

Comment: @A.Lake If you want help, post the necessary information.  In your example `OrderNo 349433` doesn't even appear on the table data, but appear in the result.  How do you expect us to help you without complete information????  Where do you get the `Qty = 3` from???  I don't see it in the data table.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric: I can spot `OrderNo 349433` in every row. And `Qty = 3` is the sum of the quantities between the "first" `Y` and the following `N`s

Comment: @Eric - I think we need a /help/how-to-read-questions page link for you on this one.  Everything you say isn't there, is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as 
 ( 
   select OrderNo, 
      -- only return the main item
      case when Regular = 'Y' then Item end AS Item, 
      Qty,
      -- assign a unique number to each `YNNN..` component group
      -- needed for GROUP BY in next step
      sum(case when Regular = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
      over (partition by OrderNo
            order by Line
            rows unbounded preceding) as grp
   from myTable
 )
select OrderNo,
   -- find the matching value for the main component
   max(Item), 
   sum(Qty)
from cte
group by OrderNo, grp
```

Comment: Originally I thought this didnt work but it was just due to a change in my data. This works brilliantly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select orderno, item, sum(qty) over(partition by regular order by regular)
from your_table 
group by  orderno, item, regular
```

Comment: order by regular will simply put them into a list of n,n,n,n,y,y,y,y and not preserve the semi-arbitrary order he has here.

Comment: Perhaps order by Line instead of order by regular would do the trick. The question was updated after this answer..

Comment: Yes, this answer came before what he was trying to do was possible.  Inclusion of line makes this solution feasible (at least in pseudo theory.   shouldn't there be a from clause?)

Answer (score 0):

Current representation is against 1st Codd's rule.

> Rule 1: The information rule: All information in a relational data
>   base is represented explicitly at the logical level and in exactly one
>   way – by values in tables.

But I believe you can still create FUNCTION/PROCEDURE and iterate row one by one with IF statement for Y/N. E.g. you create new table, IF Y - add new row to table, IF N - add +1 to QTY to latest row.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two separate tables: manufacturer & part, to get the values so you don't have to hand-jam each inventory, or care about where they fall in the invoice list.

[[image: Sample Manufacturer List][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGuaB.png)
[[image: Sample Part List]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QLPk.png)

Then, all you would need to do is compare the values to the part table to get this data. It's more work upfront, but will pay off to have this all saved and stored. A future sample query would look something like:

```
SELECT OrderNo.OrderTable, Item.OrderTable, Sum(Qty.OrderTable) AS Quantity
FROM OrderTable INNER JOIN Part ON OrderTable.Item = Table.PartName
GROUP BY OrderNo.OrderTable, Item.OrderTable, Regular.OrderTable, Part.ParentID;
```

Comment: What's the manufacturer table for? All you need is the `ParentID` in the part table. Of course you might have nested parts, i.e. *parts explosion* or *bill of materials* and then you need recursion...

Comment: I just assume that if you have a parts table, you'll have multiple manufacturers that you want to track as well.

I'd just hate to recommend a Parts table to find manufacturers listed as words instead of referencing a table.

Comment: But you also got an `OrderNo`, so there must be an `Orders` table and suppliers and customers and... :-)

Comment: You would think -- but I wouldn't assume that from this table alone. I can't tell if the order# is generated for the customer, or if it comes from a PO. Manufacturers and Suppliers aren't necessarily the same company.